# Finding a Lyapunov function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lyapunov-functions

I'm trying to find a Lyapunov function in the system

$$\begin{cases}
x'=x^2-1 \\
y'=-xy
\end{cases}
 $$

for the points $(-1,2)$ and $(1,2)$.

First, I'm confused, because this points are not singular points of the system. So, is the question wrong?

Well, if that is the case, assume the singularities $(1,0), (-1,0)$

I tried something like $V(x,y)=ax^3+by^2$, but this leads me to $\dot{V}=2ax^4-2ax^2-2bxy^2$, and I can't do anything.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You should either shift your points to the origin first or try a function with the minimum at your point.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$$
y' = -\frac{x}{x^2-1} y\Rightarrow \ln y = -\frac 12\ln(x^2-1)+c_1\Rightarrow y^2(x^2-1) = c_2
$$

so

$$
V(x,y) =  y^2(x^2-1) - c_2
$$

is a movement integral and also a Lyapounov function for this dynamic system.